Defective ASRock Trx50 WS Motherboard
Bought a ASRock TRX50 WS motherboard which I believe only come with DDR5 slots for the ram. DDR5 doesn’t fit and DDR4 doesn’t fit either. Initially I thought someone repacked or returned a DDR4 stick in a DDR5 box and sent it back to Amazon. But opon buying another set of DDR5 ram and scavenging a DDR4 stick to compare it turns out neither fit in the motherboard.
[motherboard[][1]2



Hey Kamil, unfortunately troubleshooting questions are off-topic for this site; we only deal with recommending new hardware, not troubleshooting existing hardware. You may get more help on Superuser. That said:

Have you tried flipping the DDR5 modules around? RAM sticks can only be inserted one way.
Can you compare the notch location of the DDR4 and the DDR5? I've (very rarely) seen a form of return fraud where someone buys RAM, removes the heat spreaders, puts them on a cheaper stick (such as DDR4 or DDR3), then returns them while keeping the actual RAM.

